# how to disable rolling effect and shadow effect in UIPICKER VIEW in ios?

Tags: ios, ios7

i am developing the one example of **UIPICKERVIEW** and i want to **disable or off** the **shadow effect** and **rolling effect** but not able to do it.do you have any idea for that ?

Source code:
pickerViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface pickerViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    UIPickerView *languageSelect;
    NSMutableArray *pickerData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *languageSelect;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *pickerData;
@end
```

pickerViewController.m file

```
#import "pickerViewController.h"

@interface pickerViewController ()

@end

@implementation pickerViewController
@synthesize languageSelect, pickerData;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pickerData= [[NSMutableArray alloc]     initWithObjects:@"English",@"Spanish",@"French",@"Greek",
             @"Japaneese",@"Korean",@"Hindi",@"English",@"Spanish",@"French",@"Greek",
             @"Japaneese",@"Korean",@"Hindi", nil];

    languageSelect = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 1000)];
    languageSelect.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    languageSelect.hidden = NO;
    languageSelect.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:languageSelect];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView; {
    return 1;
}

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:   (NSInteger)component; 
{
    return [pickerData count];
}
    - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;

    NSString* labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[pickerData objectAtIndex:row]];

if (pickerLabel == nil) {
    CGSize size = [labelText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, 216) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 250, size.height + 25);
    pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
    [pickerLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        // trying to mess with the UIView of the row itself... to no avail
    //CGRect rowFrame = view.frame;
    //NSLog(@"%f",rowFrame.size.height);
    //rowFrame.size.height = size.height + 25;
    //view.frame = rowFrame;
}

[pickerLabel setText:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row]];

//NSLog(@"%f",[pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height);

return pickerLabel;
}

-(NSString*) pickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{ 

}
```

Output:

[image]

I want to do something like this...!!

[image]

Comment: if you wanna achieve like this you ve to develop your own custom control this is default one

Comment: ok can u suggest me how to devlop custom control ?

Comment: s you can even use UItableView to show option's like this

Comment: ok,i will try using UITable View but in table view how can i set title row as in UIPicker view.

Comment: well you ve to use same array how you loading picker you ve to set those datasource to tableView also and other function's also same when you tap a cell you can fetch the selected data

Comment: OK, Thanks @Yohan i am trying, if any problem occur i will tell you...! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot of custom work. If you want to achieve that look, you are probably better of trying to use a [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You'll still have to put in quite some effort though.

Answer (score 0):

> In pic you can see structure of UIPickerView.
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFAKV.png

[image]

> Maybe removing some layers help you 
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2xDO.png

[image]

Comment: because any readers can't select or copy any of your code. There is a code block tag in SO's markdown subset for a reason.
Besides, the best representation of textual data is for it to be displayed as text, not as an image.

Comment: @Tim Do you can select & copy from paper book? This screenshots are example. It is good practice when you not copy&pase and write you own code.

Comment: I don't use a paper book for my full time work as an iOS Developer. I use online resources in order to retrieve small snippets of code that I can dissect and manipulate myself.
This isn't a paper book, this is a website, and there are standards for the display of this type of information.